# Solving an inequality for real exponent

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm trying to solve the inequality below for $t \in \mathbb{R}$, but I'm failing in it. Assume that $f \in [-1,1]$, $m > 0$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

$$\left(m^{\frac{1-f}{2}}+t \frac{1-f}{2} m^{-\frac{1+f}{2}} a\right)^{\frac{2}{1-f}} > 0.
$$

My main problem is the exponent, because $2/(1-f)$ is a real number. Then, the parity can not help, for example, when $f \in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. I feel that finding a general inequality isolating $t$ is not possible, but I'm not sure. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

The core issue here is the solution set of the inequality
$$
x^y > 0
$$
where $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$ are such that $x^y$ is a well-defined real number.  There are a few cases.

- If $x > 0$, then $x^y > 0$ holds for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.
- If $x = 0$, then $x^y > 0$ holds if and only if $y = 0$ and we adopt the convention that $0^0 = 1$ (rather than leaving $0^0$ undefined).
- If $x < 0$, then $x^y$ is a well-defined real number if and only if $y = \pm p/q$ is a rational number in reduced form such that $q$ is odd, and $x^y > 0$ if and only if $p$ is even and $q$ is odd.

---

Now let's solve the original inequality
$$
\left(m^{\frac{1-f}{2}}+t \frac{1-f}{2} m^{-\frac{1+f}{2}} a\right)^{\!\frac{2}{1-f}} > 0.
$$
The exponent is undefined when $f = 1$, so let's assume $f \in [-1, 1)$.
With the substitution
$$
k = \frac{1 - f}{2} \in (0, 1],
$$
we rewrite the inequality as
$$
(m^k + a k m^{k - 1} t)^{1/k} > 0.
$$
Now we apply the cases above.  Note that $1/k \in [1, +\infty)$ is nonzero.

- If $m^k + a k m^{k - 1} t > 0$, then
  $1 + a k m^{-1} t > 0$ since $m > 0$, so
  $$
  at > - \frac{m}{k}.
  $$
  Isolating $t$ on the left hand side requires casing on the sign of $a$ and is left as an exercise to the reader.
- If $m^k + a k m^{k - 1} t < 0$, then $k = p/q \ge 1$ is a rational number in reduced form such that $p$ is even and $q$ is odd.  In this case,
  $$
  at < - \frac{m}{k}.
  $$
  If we write $f = x/y \in [-1, 1)$ in reduced form (where $y > 0$), then
  $$
  k = \frac{1 - f}{2} = - \frac{x - y}{2y}.
  $$
  Note that $\gcd(x - y, y) = \gcd(x, y) = 1$, so in order for $k$ to have an even numerator and odd denominator in reduced form, we need $x - y$ to be a multiple of $4$, so
  $$ x \equiv y \equiv 1 \mathbin{\text{or}} 3 \pmod{4}. $$
  (Of course, this alone does not guarantee that $\gcd(x, y) = 1$.)